# Multiple shaders inside one Main OpenGL program

Tags: opengl, graphics, fragment-shader

I am trying to attach different shaders to different program inside my OpenGL main program so as to render different objects. More specifically, I have a planet object(obj), I want to render it into two different planets, one with bump mapping the other with multiple textures.

I came up with the following framework but it didn't work.

```
void setUp(){
   planet_1_programID = createProgramAndAttachShader(parameters...)
   planet_2_programID = createProgramAndAttachShader(parameters...)
}
void sendDataToOpenGL(){
    create VAO and bind the VAO
    load data into a VBO
    send the data to OpenGL
}

void paintGL(void){
    glm::mat4 lookatMatrix = ...
    glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = ...
    glm::mat4 lookatMatrix = ...        
    glm::mat4 transformationMatrix = ... 

    // planet 1
    glUseProgram(planet_1_programID)
    bind to the previous created VAO
    bind texture information
    some model transformation
    glDrawArrays();

    // planet 2
    glUseProgram(planet_2_programID)
    bind to the previous created VAO
    bind texture information
    some model transformation
    glDrawArrays();
}
```

The rendering result is that only one planet shows up in the final scene. I am wondering if I am understanding the function glUseProgram in an incorrect way. Can anyone give me some hints?

[update] Is it because I need to define all the variables all over again after glUseProgram? Currently I define most of the variables before glUseProgram because these two planets will have basically the same variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "define all the variables"? If you're referring to setting tho program uniforms -- then yes, they are per-program so you must set them to each program individually -- unless you use a uniform buffer object. Also you may look at program pipeline objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because I need to define all the variables all over again after glUseProgram? Currently I define most of the variables before glUseProgram because these two planets will have basically the same variables.

If you're referring to "uniforms", then something(!) like that is your problem. You see, uniform values are stored *per program* so you have to set the uniform values at least once for each program. It's not necessary to do it after each and every `glUseProgram`, but you have to do it at least once for each "`glUseProgram`".

Comment: But suppose my uniform MVP matrix are the same for all the objects. Do I need to set them each one of them after every use program?

Comment: @LouisKuang: The values of the uniforms are stored in the program objects. So you *must* set the values at least once for every program. If you think that this is inefficient: Yes it is, which is why *Uniform Buffer Objects* are a thing: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object